# flutter display text with special characters

Tags: flutter, dart, char, flutter-text

How can I render text with the special chars like ***&#039;*** in flutter

I have tried using Runnes and Ut8 but not getting the rquired result

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to render this `&#039;` to this **'** !

use [html_unscape](https://pub.dev/packages/html_unescape) package.

```
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';

main() {
  var unescape = HtmlUnescape();
  var text = unescape.convert("&#039;");
  print(text); // '
}
```